# Order by Sum of second-level association

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Let's say my application has the following classes: `Teacher`, `Class`, and `Student`. A teacher has many classes and a student belongs to a class. I'd like to be able to query my teachers and order them by the number of students they have and to do this ordering in the database. Here is the code I am currently using:

```
this._dbContext.Teachers.OrderBy((teacher) => teacher.Classes.Sum(c => c.Students.Count))
```

This code works, but the ordering is evaluated client-side. For each class the teacher teaches it is running a query to select the `COUNT` of the students. Is there a different way I can write that query to get it to do the ordering along with the original query all at once?

Comment: Wouldn't a `.ToList()` force the execution on the server. I'm not sure how much data you are dealing with and if this is a good idea in all scenarios. Also, executing RawSQL/Stored Procedure would also move the burden of the execution, in this instance, to the DB server.

Comment: The trick is to avoid aggregate of aggregate (Sum of Count) and use single aggregate (Count), e.g, `teacher.Classes.SelectMany(c => c.Students).Count()`